# How to display comments under it's respective articles

Tags: php, mysql, comments

please i need your help with my script. I have a website whereby some content headers are put into an archive box, so that when the headers are clicked the content displays. My issue is about the comment that are made on each page.

Normally i pass the page ID with a GET, so if the GET is not set, that means, the article on display is the current article, and the id for it is passed into the WHERE query manually.

The problem is that the comments left by users on old archives article are not displayed on their respective article pages, but on the article of which i passed the ID manually.
 How can i fix this problem

Here is a bit of the code i'm trying to make work.

Thanks for your time and patience.

```
                   $page_name = 'about'; 
                    $id = "";
                    if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
                    $id = $_GET['id'];
  //display content based on the header       clicked
  } else {
  //display content of the current article       based on the id. I pass the numeric id              of the current article into the where       clause that selects the content
   //it displays
  }




 $query6 = mysql_query(" SELECT c.body          FROM comment AS c  
     INNER JOIN about AS a ON
     c.article_id = a.about_id
     WHERE   c.article_id =  3
     AND page_name = '".$page_name."'")
```

**Comment Table**

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`comment`(
     `comment_id` int(255),
     `article_id` int(255),
     `username` varchar(255) ,
     `page_name` varchar(255) ,
     `comment_body` varchar(300),
     `comment_date` datetime,
     PRIMARY KEY (`comment_id`)
```

**About Table**

```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `about` (
  `about_id` int(255),
  `about_head` varchar(255)
  `about_content` varchar(4000),
  `about_tags` varchar(255) ,
  `about_created` datetime,
```

the URL for old articles

```
http://localhost/root/about.php?id=3
```

while the URL for the current article is

```
 http://localhost/root/about.php
```

so as it is now the current article doenst pass any dynamic id.
  if i do '".$id."' in the query, and i click the current article nothing is displayed.

Comment: Where is your problem? Code or query? If query, can you post some of your mysql structure here? (comments table too)

Comment: Is your `old archives article` stored in some other table?

Comment: @webbandit Yes the archive are stored in the db also, inside the respective pages they appear in.. I've updated the question with table structure of both comments and about pages.

Comment: Look, in your query you have `AND page_name = '".$page_name."'"`. I don't see no `page_name` column in any of your tables.

Comment: @dotunoyesanmi Where are you making use of `$id = $_GET['id'];` further in the code ? Also is `page_name = 'about'` for every record ?

Comment: @vedarthk  .... I'm using the GET ['id'] to check if an old article was clicked, if so it should display the content else the current article should be displayed. The id for that current article is passed to the query manually.

Comment: @webbadict... It was a typo, i've updated the question

Comment: @dotunoyesanmi Is page_name = 'about' for every record in the comment table ? You are defining a static value `$page_name = 'about'` ?

Comment: @vedarthk ... The page_name is the name on which the article appears.. This also go in the where clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
 WHERE   c.article_id =  3
```

should presumably be

```
 WHERE   c.article_id =  $id
```

Although **PLEASE** note that would be vulnerable to SQL injection.  You should instead use prepared statements, into which you pass your variables as parameters that do not get evaluated for SQL.  If you don't know what I'm talking about, or how to fix it, read the story of [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: @dotunoyesanmi: How do you determine which article in your db is the 'current' one?

Comment: First i check for the id, if isset, then it fetches the row that matches the id and display the content. But if it's not, then i pass the id to the query manually.i.e it's not dynamic.

Comment: Okay, so assign the fixed `id` of the 'current' article to `$id` in the `else` clause of your `if` statement.

Comment: Will it be sensible if i give it an id = 0 ?
If i gave it another id other than that, it'll probably affect/match an id of the archive article.

Comment: I don't think that having a constant ID for your most recent article is a very good idea at all.  Far better to determine the most recent article from the `about_created` column?

Comment: Okay, if i use the about_created field to determine. Using ORDER BY about_created DESC ... How do i choose the first row, since the most recent will appear at the top.
Thanks.

Comment: `ORDER BY about_created DESC LIMIT 1`